# How can I resize any image without loosing any quality

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resize, image-quality

Very new to this, but I have an image that is 9.7" × 14.5" and I want to resize it to 9" x 12", I know this will need cropping, but I would love to print it, so wouldn't want to loose any quality.

What is the best way of getting this done in photoshop? or is there an online website that has an online re-sizer?

I am very new to this, so if you could please maybe write down a small step by step process of how this could be done in photoshop, I would be very grateful.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Photoshop, select Image>Image Size...
In the Image Size dialog, first uncheck "**Resample Image,**" then set your document width to 9". (width will change to 13.454, and resolution will bump up to 323.33).
Then crop the height down to 12" and you're done.